# How can I pass both type [Struct] and [Int] into [AnyObject] array?

Tags: ios, swift

I currently want to pass 2 arrays from the view controller represented as [Prepaid] and [Int] into another view. In that view, I created an array with the type AnyObject but error. Here is my code:

In view controller:

```
struct Prepaid {
    var title: String?
    var percent: Int
    
    init(title: String?, percent: Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.percent = percent
    }
}

func passData() {

    var prepaidDatas: [Prepaid] = []
    var prepaidMonths: [Int] = [6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48]
    
    prepaidSlider.type = .prepaid
    prepaidSlider.step = 5
    prepaidSlider.delegate = self
    prepaidSlider.stepsData = prepaidDatas //error: Cannot assign value of type '[DownPayment]' to type '[AnyObject]'
            
    monthSlider.type = .month
    monthSlider.step = 3
    monthSlider.delegate = self
    monthSlider.stepsData = prepaidMonths //error: Cannot assign value of type '[Int]' to type '[AnyObject]'

}
```

And in my custom view, I create an array to receive the data like this:

```
var stepsData: [AnyObject] = []
```

And I got this errors (sorry for upload the picture of error. But I don't know how to describle in English). Now how can I solve all of those errors:
[image]

Comment: You need to cast the `AnyObject` instead: `if let floatValue = value as? Float { ... }`

Comment: Use Any, not AnyObject. Except don't. Use specific types.

Comment: Swift's way could be `enum Group { case number(Int), other(String) }`

Comment: @ChanOnly123 In this case rather a protocol constraint and a generic type.

Comment: A slider will always operate on numbers. The UI component itself uses `Float`, therefore it makes no sense to pass any other typ of data. If you want to convert the values to other objects, use a separate converting function that gets the float value from slider.